# python self.session doesn't save data correctly

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine, session

I'm developing a webapp using Google App Engine and Python.
I'm facing a strange problem and i don't know how to solve it and what causes it.
When I fill a form I send the data for checking them. If they aren't complete and some fields are missed the server send the form back with an advice "FILL ALL THE FIELDS!".

That's work pretty well.

What I'm trying to do is sending the form back with the "description" and "title" fields filled with what the user has written before submitting the form, so he must to fill only the unfilled fields (and he doesn't need to rewrite everything from the beginning).

That's the code:

```
class SaleAnnCheck(BaseHandler):
  def post(self):
    title = self.request.POST.get('title')
    cat = self.request.POST.get('cat')
    description = self.request.POST.get('description')
    AcqOpt = self.request.POST.get('AcqOpt')
    lat = self.request.POST.get('lat')
    lng = self.request.POST.get('lng')
    image1 = self.request.POST.get("file1", None)
    image2 = self.request.POST.get("file2", None)
    image3 = self.request.POST.get("file3", None)
    logging.info("info sale announcment")
    logging.info(title)
    logging.info(cat)
    logging.info(description)
    logging.info(AcqOpt)
    logging.info(lat)
    logging.info(lng)
    logging.info(image1)
    logging.info(image2)
    logging.info(image3)
    self.session["ECommerceUser"]["description"]=description
    self.session["ECommerceUser"]["title"]=title
    logging.info('session')
    logging.info(self.session["ECommerceUser"])
    if title == '' or cat == None or description == '' or AcqOpt == None or lat == '' or lng == '':
      error = 'empty'
      urlR='/CreateSaleAnn?'+urllib.urlencode({'error':'empty'})
      self.redirect(urlR)


class Create(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    error = self.request.get('error')
    if error == 'empty':
      logging.info('sbagliato')
      logging.info(self.session["ECommerceUser"])
      template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/CreateAnnouncement.html')
      w = self.response.write
      w(template.render({'error':'FILL ALL THE MANDATORY FIELDS!', 'description': self.session["ECommerceUser"]["description"], 'title':  self.session["ECommerceUser"]["title"]}))
    else:
      logging.info('giusto')    
      logging.info(self.session["ECommerceUser"])   
      template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('templates/CreateAnnouncement.html')
      w = self.response.write
      w(template.render({'description': self.session["ECommerceUser"]["description"], 'title':  self.session["ECommerceUser"]["title"]}))
```

When I submit the form the content is checked by making an HTTP post request to a certain URL, handled by SaleAnnCheck.

Description and Title are saved in the session correctly (i checked it by printing the content of self.session["ECommerceUser"] in the logs). Then, if a field isn't filled, the server redirect again to the form page, by a GET request to a related URL.

The requests to that URL is handled by Create. But when i try to render the HTML template of the form (using jinja2) with the previous typed values of Description and Title the related text areas are not filled with that values.
It happens because self.session["ECommerceUser"]["description"] and self.session["ECommerceUser"]["title"] are empty, but they weren't when i checked them before (in SaleAnnCheck).

Why it happens? Any explanation? It's a weird problem and there aren't any tips or suggestion about on internet

Comment: You are saving variables as sessions, redirecting the page, then retrieving the session for another function. This is not the best architecture for just passing variables. Try searching for Python HTTP Requests and Promises.

Answer (score 0):

This is because 'self.session' is not a Session, it's just a class variable and will not be readable outside the class. If you really want to use persistent sessions for storing variables, try something like this:

From the docs:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

```
s = requests.Session()

s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies/set/sessioncookie/123456789')
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies')
```

Comment: I've used since now Session in the way is described in this documentation: http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html. I haven't had any problem except that. When I do the login the app store the info about login inside the session (in the same way I did for SaleAnnCheck) and it works. I can read all the infos about login everywhere. The Login is handled by another class, in another python module. So why it works?